# Add subtitle in shinydashboard title section

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to add a subtitle with smaller font size in shinydashboard title section under the main title?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title= div(h3('Títutlo', style="margin: 0;"), h4('subtitulo', style="margin: 0;"))
    ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]